Movie with (humorous) fail of a dancer in corps?
I’m trying to find a particular movie (that I saw, sometime in the last 40 years or so), that shows a corps de ballet with one dancer out of synch with the rest of the group. The failing dancer is one of the protagonists in the movie — I really don’t remember the plot line, except something like “struggling young dancer” feels right.
I don’t think it’s “Turning Point”, or “Black Swan” (it may be), but there surely are other options?
Funny how the image has stuck in my memory: full corps around the perimeter of the stage (except the downstage side), maybe two rows. The dancers are “sitting” on the floor, and they are executing a swaying movement from left to right and back again, multiple times, except for this one dancer who is swaying right to left and back —- and sticks out, so very obviously. She is mid-stage left, in a corps of perhaps two dozen dancers, as I recall. (Weird that I don’t have the vocabulary to describe this.).
My interest is in having a video snippet showing how ballet, when done right, is perfect and appears effortless, yet it’s so easy to do something wrong, and have it be obviously wrong in ballet. In retirement, I am taking a class where we are reviewing various styles of dance.
Any idea what the movie I’m struggling to remember is?

Welcome to Movies & TV SE! To increase your chances of getting a good answer, please [edit] your question and add more details, such as when you watched the movie (even an approximate decade is helpful). For more tips on how to improve your question, take a look at our guide on asking identification questions.

Also note that this is not the platform to ask for video snippets showing some particular thing. I'm not sure that was your intention, but I just want to make sure you are aware of this.

After reading comments to original post, and a little more sleuthing on the web, here’s the answer to my original question:
Turns out the movie I had in mind was “The Turning Point” (1977). I did find a still shot on the web from the film; the film sequence from which this still was taken is quite hilarious.

